# Postfix Mail Server does not send mail

Tags: postfix, email-server

Installation for the mail server is successful after executing these commands:

```
sudo DEBIAN_PRIORITY=low apt install postfix echo 'export MAIL=~/Maildir' | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/mail.sh source /etc/profile.d/mail.sh
```

but when wanted to check by sending email to my self by this command

```
echo 'init' | s-nail -s 'init' -Snorecord sammy
```

when I check maildir by `ls -R ~/Maildir`

this dir is empty and doesn't desire output like this:

This is what I expect after ls command

```
Output /home/sammy/Maildir/: cur new tmp

/home/sammy/Maildir/cur:

/home/sammy/Maildir/new: 1463177269.Vfd01I40e4dM691221.mail.example.com

/home/sammy/Maildir/tmp:
```

Comment: Check your logs.